# CSS Automatically changing space width to align text lines

Tags: css, text, alignment, line

I have text inside div.

What I want to do is make lines same width, so space automatically changes to align lines, like you can do in Word.

Can it be done with html and css?

Comment: try `text-align:justify` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
div {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

More info **[here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-justify/)**

Comment: Done. Ty. although I'm not friend of text inside a div without any other tag :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `text-align: justify;`
Working copy is here:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eros velit, dictum id libero quis, porttitor volutpat odio. In et lectus a ligula pulvinar egestas. Nullam ornare turpis ac dui efficitur commodo. Mauris laoreet cursus lorem, quis congue neque venenatis vel. Nullam eu maximus nulla, vitae fermentum nisl. Sed eu euismod elit, eget consequat lorem. Suspendisse eget interdum elit. Nullam convallis massa magna, quis scelerisque orci sollicitudin eget. Curabitur porta nibh nisl, at tempor leo vulputate quis. Nam eget nibh turpis. Suspendisse ac ex finibus, consectetur nunc ac, dapibus sapien. Curabitur eleifend ut mauris quis sodales. Aenean viverra ante non mauris egestas, sed pellentesque dolor tempus. Donec rhoncus quis magna posuere fermentum.swdjsdlkalksdnlds jdhjfhdskjnhckjdsnc
  </p>
```